# Which is the better module for shopping cart?

Tags: ubercart

I would like to use a shopping cart module in my site.

Can any one suggest which would be the better one with basic functionality like displaying content (media), cost, adding to cart, billing, etc. It must include all necessary features of a shopping cart.

Will Ubercart fulfill the basic requirements?

Comment: When you say *shopping cart*, I'm assuming you actually mean *e-commerce system*, correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the sounds of it, you actually want a whole e-commerce system, not just a shopping cart.

Ubercart will do this for you, but the general trend now is to go with Drupal Commerce ([project page](http://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) | [Commerce homepage](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/)).

Both modules will allow for shopping carts, as well as integration with a variety of payment service providers.  I'd personally go with Drupal Commerce.  It seems a little more difficult than Ubecart at first glance, but once you get over that you'll realise it is much more flexible/powerful.

Try using the [Commerce Quickstart](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart) installation profile to get yourself familiar/started with it.

There are a lot of good videos for Commerce as well such as [Selling Content with Drupal Commerce using Content Access and Roles](http://commerceguys.com/blog/selling-content-drupal-commerce-using-content-access-and-roles) from the Commerce Guys.

Lastly, there is a blog post [here](http://www.markroyko.com/blog/2011/12/14/ubercart-3-vs-drupal-commerce) that weighs up the pros and cons of each system (although it is from 2011)

Edit:

You might find the [getting started](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/getting-started) guide useful also.

Comment: Totally agree with this; Commerce used to confuse the hell out of me but now I've 'got it' I wouldn't even give Ubercart a second glance (sorry Ubercart!)

Comment: Also (for anyone who hasn't seen it yet), there's a nice distribution called [MartPlug](http://drupal.org/project/martplug) which provides an already-setup Commerce store along with a nice clean HTML5 theme...not too shabby

Comment: Commerce is awesome :-)  Like I mentioned, the learning curve is steeper - but after the initial shock it gives you a million more options.

Comment: _the learning curve is steeper_...just wouldn't be Drupal if that wasn't true would it? ;)

Comment: Martplug is great for seeing how Commerce works, I'd completely forgotten about that!  It's what I used when I wanted to play with Commerce.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation @Chapabu i am new to e-commerce hence my terminology may vary. just implementing it in my localhost.

Comment: No problem!  If you run into any issues don't forget to check out the [tag:drupal-commerce] tag.  There's loads of support here that will no doubt make everything so much easier!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple and easy to configure e-commerce solution for Drupal 7, try the [Light Shop](https://drupal.org/project/lightshop) module.

However, do note that it doesn't provide any payment integration (only e-mail notifications are there).